# How can I defer loading elpy using use-package?

Tags: use-package, elpy

I've been updating all my use-package calls now that `:idle` is no longer a decent way to defer stuff. At the moment one of the biggest hits on my load time is `elpy` which loads a whole bunch of additional modules. At the moment my invocation is rather basic:

```
(use-package elpy
  :commands elpy-enable
  :init (elpy-enable)
  :config
  (progn
    (setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi"
          elpy-rpc-project-specific 't)
    (when (fboundp 'flycheck-mode)
      (setq elpy-modules (delete 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules)))))
```

However this is rather wasteful if I'm never editing any python modules. The trouble is elpy is a collection of modes so I can't just use the mode binding form as `elpy-enable` needs to get called. So what approach should I use. Is it just a case of triggering on the python-mode hook?

Comment: I just stopped tracking the MELPA version of use-package. It seems :idle was removed with nothing to replace it. I'll just wait until a replacement pops up.

Comment: @abo-abo: I can understand why, :idle is a bit of a hack. Really for proper on-demand loading it should be triggered by an event other than "some time passed".

Comment: `:idle` can be replaced with something like `:defer 30` where the number is the delay in seconds after which the package should be loaded.

Comment: @kaushalmodi, does that already work?

Comment: @abo-abo I haven't tried but it probably should. I read that update in yesterday's commit. The README is also updated with that info.

Comment: If you rarely use Python and you need to call `elpy-enable` to be able to use elpy then I would call the whole `(use-package elpy ..)` in the `python-mode-hook` without `:init` and `:commands` sections and put `(elpy-enable)` as the last form in `:config`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don’t know Elpy, so I’m not sure whether I understand your problem correctly.  I do know `use-package`, though, and recently suffered from the very same issue, namely the removal of `:idle`.

Basically, there are two ways out, depending on how you need to use Elpy.  You can either use a poor man’s `:idle`, with `run-with-idle-timer`, e.g.

```
:init (run-with-idle-timer 10 nil #'elpy-enable)
```

Alternatively, you can rely on good old `with-eval-after-load` or use `python-mode-hook` and delay Elpy until after Python Mode is loaded or enabled respectively:

```
:init (add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'elpy-enable)
;; or
:init (with-eval-after-load 'python (elpy-enable))
```

Comment: If elpy was a simple mode it would be fine. However really it's a bunch of minor-modes stitched together to make the python experience more integrated. As such the elpy-enable step has to be run before the first python file is loaded so all the modules are configured and ready.

Comment: @stsquad with-eval-after-load should do exactly that.

Comment: I need to add `:commands elpy-enable` to make it works. `:init (with-eval-after-load 'python (elpy-enable))
  :commands elpy-enable`

Answer (score 6):

The author of elpy suggests doing this via an advice, because `elpy-enable` modifies the `python-mode-hook` variable, so calling it inside the mode-hook is too late: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/wiki/Configuration

simple approach:

```lisp
(package-initialize)
(advice-add 'python-mode :before 'elpy-enable)
```

using `use-package`:

```lisp
(use-package elpy :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  (advice-add 'python-mode :before 'elpy-enable))
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this when I couldn't. [I've given feedback](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1566#issuecomment-496956436) to the maintainer that IMHO this is the wrong place to hide this information. It's also in the official [`README.rst`](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/blob/master/README.rst), but not in the first and most obvious place to look: [the installation section of the documentation](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#installation). I've reported this in [issue #1606](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1606).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @stsquad, please consider marking this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is possible with :after

```
(use-package python
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :mode ("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))

(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :after python
  :config (elpy-enable))
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Also you don't need `:defer` if you already use `:mode`. https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#notes-about-lazy-loading